# MySQL return All records between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to retrieve all records between two dates and the MySQL query is bringing back records with a completely different date.

My Query Is

```
SELECT datecreated FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS WHERE datecreated BETWEEN '01/08/2015' AND '24/08/2015'
```

The result from that query is this:

[image]

As you can tell the dates returned are not in the boundary specified in the SQL Query.

My Question is how do I fix this?

Comment: What data type is the `datecreated` column?

Comment: The data type is DateTime

Comment: @thomasjcf21 : how come your accepted answer gives wrong output...!! Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb08c/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT datecreated FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS WHERE datecreated BETWEEN
 to_date('01/08/2015','MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date('24/08/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

**Solution 2**

```
SELECT datecreated FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS WHERE datecreated >='01/08/2015' AND datecreated <= '24/08/2015'
```

**Solution 3**

```
SELECT datecreated  FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS 
where 
    datecreated >='01/08/2015 06:42:10' and datecreated <='24/08/2015 06:42:50';
```

Forgive me I didn't see that Time part I thought it is a different column. This should work (I messed with time field to see if there is a difference as all your Times are in 12)

Comment: The query responded with function to_date does not exist.

Comment: This one should do it : SELECT datecreated FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS WHERE datecreated >='01/08/2015' AND datecreated <= '24/08/2015'

Comment: The query returned the exact same as the picture above.

Comment: Is it a DateTime field or Date only ?

Comment: Try the thirs solution please.

Comment: @thomasjcf21 If that worked, this is not a MySQL question.

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa : none of the solution is correct for `datetime` datatype in mysql. check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb08c/3

Comment: Does the fact that this worked for him bothers that much it deserves a downgrade ?

Answer (score 2):

Give this format a try:

```
SELECT datecreated 
FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS 
WHERE datecreated BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-24'

SELECT datecreated 
FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS 
WHERE datecreated BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2015','%d-%m-%Y') 
and STR_TO_DATE('24/08/2015','%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: It returned back with zero records sorry.

Comment: flip the month and day then

Comment: @Drew : your query excluded data on right boundary. Means any datetime between  `24/08/2015 00:00:01` and `24/08/2015 23:59:59` is excluded.

Comment: @seahawk, true [pastie](http://pastie.org/10373521), we never got to times in the question, by then I didn't want to pester the OP anymore, let him work it thru with the correct answer. thx bud :>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datecreated 
FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS 
WHERE datecreated >= '2015-08-01 00:00:00' 
AND datecreated < '2015-08-25 00:00:00'
;
```

You could do `BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-24 23:59:59'`; but if MySQL ever started storing more precise data in these fields, it could cause issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT datecreated FROM TABLE_COMPLAINTS WHERE CAST(datecreated as DATE) BETWEEN '20150801' AND '20150824'
```

This is assuming your datecreated column is a DateTime type

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TABLE_COMPLAINTS where date(datecreated)
between STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2015',"%d/%m/%Y") and
STR_TO_DATE('24/08/2015',"%d/%m/%Y") ;
```